# Display wilcox test result along with a plot PDF

Tags: r

I wrote a function that will generate a plot for each class of data, and I also created a function that will perform the wilcox test for all the classes, and for each class alone.

What I want to do is to take the result of this test, and display it inside each specific PDF for each class. Can this be done in a nice way?

That's the code of the function that I'm using to perform wilcox test:

```
library(ggplot2)
t = read.table("data.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
uni = unique(c(t$V9))

testresult<- function(column, datacol) {    
  if(column=="PP") {
    for (xp in uni) { 
      for(yp in uni) {
        testx<- subset(t, V9==xp)
        testy<- subset(t, V9==xp)
        zz = wilcox.test(testx[[datacol]],jitter(testy[[datacol]]))
        print(p1)
        p1 = c(xp)
        p2 = c(yp)
        pv = c(zz$p.value)
      }
    }
  } 
}
for (x in uni) { 
  test<-subset(t, V9==x)
  dat <- melt(test, measure=c("V1", "V2" , "V3" , "V4"))

  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(Class,value , color=variable)) + 
       geom_boxplot() + 
       geom_point(position="jitter" , alpha=0.3) +  
       facet_grid(variable~., scales="free_y")
       ggsave(paste("ggplot2/",paste(x,".pdf")), p, width=25, height=15)
}
```

I tried to fill it inside a list, or inside a data frame, but it didn't work that way.

Comment: you've asked several questions related to this same issue and have provided a reproducible example in exactly zero of them. There are many people here who would love to help you, but the current structure of your questions makes it nearly impossible to provide any reasonable answers. R provides the very nice function `dput()` which makes it very easy for others to copy and run your code. As it stands, nobody can make any assessment about your code because we have NO idea about the structure of `data.txt`.

Comment: look at http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob if you don't want to go down the path of learning sweave.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use Sweave to generate nice PDF reports mixing text and plots.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but how can i use this ?? i'm new in R , can you give me an example in my case

Comment: Topic on Sweave is too broad to be covered in an answer. Open your favorite web search and type something akin to "sweave demo". http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/Sweave/ should get you started.

Comment: thank you very much , but i might need a simpler way in the mean time , as i mentioned in my reply on Chase comment

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to display it within each plot? As the title, annotated within the plot region itself? Here are a few options.

```
#No sample data provided, so we use this instead.
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))

ggplot(dat , aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point() +
opts(title = "hi world") +  #This line makes a title
geom_text(aes(max(x),max(y), label=paste("The mean of x = ", round(mean(x),3), sep = " ")), hjust = 1, size = 3)     #This line annotates within the plot region
```

Comment: thanks for your help , i want to display the result as a table in another page of the PDF file , and i want it to be generated automatically for each class of data.
as you can see in my code , i have for each (xp,yp) a p-value , soo i want a matrix that have these columns for each class in the data : 
xp yp p-value signification

Comment: hello , is this can be done in a simple way like filling them in a matrix and then add them to the plot?? or should i use the sweave thing ?? thanks

Comment: that's a part of the txt file that i'm working on , http://www.mediafire.com/?mnj26kp4bv5lcr5 , the only thing i want is to output the result of the test as i said , in a table of 4 columns based on each (xp,yp) , thnx in advance